# Looking to mimic Netgear Nighthawk AC1900 Router Settings in a TP-Link MR3040 Router

Tags: ip, router, static-ip, netgear, tp-link

I have a Netgear Nighthawk AC1900 Router that is setup and working correctly with a network that has two Wifi cameras and a Linux PC acting as a server.

Static IP addresses have been assigned to both WiFi cameras and the Linux PC in the Netgear Router:

[image]

The router is using a Cat5 ethernet cable for two way communication for the Linux PC that is acting as a server:

[image]

Now I am trying to replace the Netgear Nighthawk router with a battery powered TP-LINK Router:

[image]

I have matched the Static IP address assignment of the Linux PC and two Wifi cameras in Netgear Nighthawk Router to the TP-LINK router settings:

[image]

The network setup is not working though, I do not know what other settings I might need to match from the Netgear Nighthawk router to the TC-LINK router.

I also do not know if the one ethernet port on the TC-LINK router will allow two way direction communication of the Cat5 cable hooked up between the Linux PC and the TC-Link wireless router so that my Linux PC can continue to act as a server on this network like it works on the Netgear Night router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that when you say "The network setup is not working though" you mean that those hosts are no longer being provided a reserved IP address via DHCP...

According to [various](https://superuser.com/questions/904476/what-is-the-difference-between-arp-binding-and-dhcp-address-reservation) [sources](http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-170.html), the ARP Binding feature of TP-Link routers isn't for assigning DHCP reservations. You'd need to either find the DHCP reservation feature on the TP-Link and add the appropriate entries in there, or statically configure the IP addresses on the devices themselves.

Comment: Perfect the fact that I was using ARP instead of DHCP bindings was the issue, thanks much!